# while selecting image from gallery image path is not returned in android

Tags: android, image

Hi I'm selecting the image from gallery in emulator. When I click the browse button and select the image, I have written the code to retrieve the path of the image. But it is not displayed. When I use Log to print the path in the logcat, it displays error. Please help me out to display the image path. This is my code.

---

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
           logo_path.setText(selectedImagePath);

        }
    }
}
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

---

Comment: Zarin, what you getting exactly?

Comment: @ Kishan Nothing displays in the field and no error too.

Comment: what error is displayed in log?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public String getImagePathFromURI(Uri uri) {

    String imgpath = "";
    Cursor c= getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    if (c == null) { 

        imgpath= uri.getPath();  // Getting path from url itself

    } else { 

        c.moveToFirst();
        int id = c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
        result = c.getString(id);
        c.close();  // Close curson.
    }

    return imgpath;  // original image path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null)
        return null;
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

and in your `onActivityResult` use

```
String path = getRealPathFromURI(uri); 
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
```